# Can FileInfo.Length be cast as an integer?

Tags: c#, casting, fileinfo

I am using FileInfo.Length in order to get the size of a file and then post it to a GoogleDoc. The problem is that I am getting negative values from FileInfo.Length....

I have looked around online for some solutions and can't find any other reason...besides the fact that FileInfo.Length should be a Long and I was casting it to an Int.....could this have something to do with it?

Here is my code:

```
                int size = (int)file.Length;
                string name = file.Name;
                googleBot.insertArchiveRow(name, size);
                progressBar.Value++;
                this.UpdateLayout();
```

Would casting cause me problems here?

Thanks!

Comment: do `var size = file.Length`

Comment: What is the value of `file.Length` and why do you need it to be `int`?

Comment: file.Length is the size of a file in bytes. These can get into the order of over 100 gigs each. So I am not surprised that I had overflow problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Casting could cause you problems.

How big is the File?

> "FileInfo.Length should be a Long and I was casting it to an Int....."

If greater than `2^31 - 1`  then casting to an `int` could be negative....

e.g.

```
        long l = (long)Math.Pow(2, 31);
        int i = (int) l;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", l);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
```

Prints:

```
2147483648
-2147483648
```

**Bottom line**: `FileInfo.Length` is a `long` , so treat it as such.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid surprises like this and let the compiler generate code to perform error checking:

```
 int size = checked((int)file.Length);
```

You'll now get an OverflowException instead of a negative value.

Comment: I wouldn't treat a filesize of > 2^31 - 1 as an exception.

Comment: Somebody ought to tell Google, I guess ;)  But the documented limits on GoogleDoc files are well south of that, 2 MB for documents, 20 MB for spreadsheets, 50 MB for presentations.

Comment: I meant in general. I wasn't aware of those limits.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, pretty easily, in fact...

```
int.MaxValue ==  2147483647 == 0x7FFFFFFF
int.MinValue == -2147483648 == 0x80000000
```

`int.MaxValue` is `2^31 - 1`, so something like ~2GB in size; any file bigger than that would read as negative, until you cycled back around again, that is. :)